# Issues with jms:inbound-channel-adapter

Tags: spring-integration

I have the following Spring Integration configuration for inbound channel Adaptor:

```
<bean id="inputQueue"
    class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="INBOUND.QUEUE" />
</bean>
<int:channel id="inputChannel">
    <int:queue ref="inputQueue"></int:queue>
</int:channel>

<jms:inbound-channel-adapter
    channel="inputChannel" connection-factory="activemqConnectionFactory"
    destination-name="inputQueue"></jms:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

I am facing issues while starting the application as it is unable to create the `inputChannel` bean. Please help.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'inputChannel': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Could not convert argument value of type [org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue] to required type [java.util.Queue]: Failed to convert value of type 'org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue' to required type 'java.util.Queue'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue' to required type 'java.util.Queue': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:697) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:192) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1270) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.Example1Application.main(Example1Application.java:12) [classes/:na]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `"org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue` doesn’t implement `Java.util.Queue`. That is what you have in the stack trace so far. On the other hand you don’t need to ad that `<queue>` declaration to the channel: you define a JMS Channel Adapter to deal with ActiveMQ.

Another your problem that you declare a `destination-name="inputQueue"`, where it is a *bean name*. You should consider to use just `destination` which is indeed a reference to a bean, or really just use that `INBOUND.QUEUE` in this `destination-name`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you please tell me, then how do I map queues and channels. This one above I can add in JMS Channel adaptor. But there is another channel in between the flow that connects two transformers. Then how do I map a queue to that channel.

Comment: You just don't map them. The `queue` is a concept of the ActiveMQ and you or listen to that or send to it use Inbound or Outbound Channel Adapter, respectively. The `channel` is a concept of Spring Integration and there is no correlation with what you have in JMS. I guess you need to read more theory: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/overview.html#overview-components-channel